# System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute doesn't exist in the namespace System.Runtime.Serialization

Tags: wcf, serialization

I'm doing some WCF work and I don't see why I run into this error.

`System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute` doesn't exist in the namespace

```
System.Runtime.Serialization
```

The microsoft documentation clearly shows this hierarchy

```
System.Object
  System.Attribute
    System.Runtime.Serialization.ContractNamespaceAttribute
```

Anyone knows what is going on?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Make sure you have added reference to the `System.Runtime.Serialization` **assembly** to your project.

Comment: @Mr. Zen, if this post helped you solve the problem you were having please [mark it as answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking on the tick next to it.

Comment: Thank you for this reminder when I had to consume a SOAP service in 2023.